# Функция с переменным числом аргументов одного конкретного типа

Tags: c++

Есть очень много похожих вопросов на этот, но конкретно на такой, как у меня, я не совсем нашёл ответ.

Как сделать функцию с переменным числом аргументов одного конкретного типа? Пусть это будет char. Т.е., чтобы её можно было вызывать с любым количеством аргументов, но чтобы обязательно они все были char. А иначе - ошибка на этапе компиляции. Так возможно сделать?

```
foo(char, char, char); //---Можно!
foo(char); //--Можно!
foo(char, char, int) //--Нельзя, ошибка на этапе компиляции
foo() //==По-хорошему, тоже надо бы запретить, но не это главное
```

Comment: Чем вариант с массивом не устраивает?

Comment: Foo(char a...);

Comment: @user31238, и что помешает написать `Foo('a', -12345678)`? *"Почитайте"* -- вот-вот, почитайте вопрос сначала.

Comment: Почитайте про функции с переменным количеством параметров

Answer (score 5):

Если у вас в распоряжении есть C++11 можно сделать так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<class ...Args>
struct Dummy{};

template<class T, class ...Args, class = Dummy<typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, Args>::value>::type...>>
void foo(const T &arg, const Args &...args){

}

int main(){
    int i = 0;
    double d = 0;

    foo(i, i);      //ok
    foo(d, d);      //ok
    //foo(i, d);    //error
}
```

Если тип вы знаете заранее, то замените `T` на этот тип

Comment: Мне нравится этот вариант, что-то я про такое даже не подумал.

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать, например, вот так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <initializer_list>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
constexpr bool allChars()
{
    return is_same<char, T>::value;
}

template<typename T1, typename T2, typename... Tail>
constexpr bool allChars()
{
    return is_same<char, T1>::value ? allChars<T2, Tail...>() : false;
}

template<typename... Chars>
enable_if_t<allChars<Chars...>()> foo(Chars... rawChars)
{
    initializer_list<char> chars{rawChars...};
    for(auto character : chars)
        cout << character << '\n';
}

int main() 
{
    foo('S', 'O');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Заинтриговал возвращаемый тип :) А если захочется что-то другое? Внести `enable...` в параметры типа не получится... Объявить разве что в теле фиктивную функцию типа `enable_if_t<allChars<Chars...>()> dummy();`?

Comment: @Harry, ну, там `void` по умолчанию. Можно заменить на что угодно: `enable_if_t<allChars<Chars...>(), MyCoolType>`

Comment: Мда, век живи - век учись... Спасибо!

Comment: `initializer_list` можно воткнуть прямо в `for`.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант `foo(char,...)` не проходит принципиально - поскольку `...` автоматически не подлежит никаким проверкам типа.

Вариант наличия массы перегрузок `foo(char)`, `foo(char,char)` и так далее - в принципе использовать можно, но никто не помешает неявному приведению, типа вызова `f(3)`.

Вариант на грани фола - `void foo(std::initializer_list<char> c)` - не подходит ровно по той же причине...

Так что "чисто функциями", похоже, не получится. Остается шаблонный вариант, но тут надо подумать... :)

P.S. Пока набирал ответ, @ixSci уже сделал это за меня :)